# jQuery ie8 Object Null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

i have a big problem and trying to solve it since hours but t doesnt word.
Everything works verywell instead of IE8.

```
var geschlechtA= jQuery('#geschlecht').find('.active').text();
var grund_basisB= jQuery('#grund_basis').find('.active').text();
var varianteC= jQuery('#variante').find('.active').text();
var farbeD= jQuery('#farbe').find('.active span').text();
var param =[geschlechtA,grund_basisB,varianteC,farbeD];
var bildDaten=[
{"geschlecht":"männlich","basis":"Business","variante":"klassisch","farbe":"schwarz/weiss","bsrc":"mydomain/img1.jpg"},
{"geschlecht":"weiblich","basis":"Bistro","variante":"leger","farbe":"jeans/weiss","bsrc":"mydomain/img2.jpg"},
{"geschlecht":"männlich","basis":"Business","variante":"klassisch","farbe":"schwarz/weiss","bsrc":"mydomain/img3.jpg"},
{"geschlecht":"männlich","basis":"Business","variante":"klassisch","farbe":"schwarz/blau","bsrc":"mydomain/img4.jpg"},
]

var found=false;

    for (var i = 0; i < bildDaten.length; i++) {
        if(bildDaten[i].geschlecht==param[0]){
            if(bildDaten[i].basis==param[1]){
                if(bildDaten[i].variante==param[2]){
                    if(bildDaten[i].farbe==param[3]){
                        found=true;
                        jQuery('#image_container img').attr('src', bildDaten[i].bsrc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    if(!found){
        jQuery('#image_container img').attr('src', bildDaten[0].bsrc);
    }
```

Im trying to make a simple Cloth configurator.
It works very well in Chrome, FF, IE9+,
But i get for ie8 the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Für die Eigenschaft "geschlecht" kann kein Wert abgerufen werden: Das Objekt ist Null oder undefiniert
```

It says for the attribute "geschlecht" couldnt get a Value, Object is NULL or undefined.

How can i fiy it?

Comment: Everyone loves reading code written in German :|

Comment: Remove comma after the last object in the `bildDaten` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 doesn't read trailing commas correctly. Remove the last comma from the `bildDaten` array.

Also try putting the code inside an anonymous closure. IE has all sorts of built-in, non-overwritable objects.

```
(function () {
  // Your code
}());
```

By the way, nested `if`s that don't have corresponding `else`s can always be refactored to `&&`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < bildDaten.length; i++) {
  if (bildDaten[i].geschlecht == param[0] &&
      bildDaten[i].basis == param[1] &&
      bildDaten[i].variante == param[2] &&
      bildDaten[i].farbe == param[3]) 
  {
    found = true;
    jQuery('#image_container img').attr('src', bildDaten[i].bsrc);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, im a bit new to jQuery :)
Any idea why it does not work with ie 8 and 9?

Comment: @user3083462 Not straight away